# Differences between 条 and 根

Tags: word-choice, mandarin, measure-word

Both of these two words 条 and 根 in the dictionary are said to be measure words for long and thin objects. What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 4):

- **條** can be a measure word for **huge things**. For example, 一条河, 一条烟囱, 一条船(all long and thin but huge) - *you can't use 根 for huge things*
- **条** can be a measure word for **living things**. For example, 一条蚯蚓, 一条蛇, 一条狗 (all long and thin and alive) - *Don't use 根 for living things*
- **条** can be a measure word for thin and long  **things with flat surface**, For example, 一条手帕. 一条毛巾 (both long and thin and have a flat surface) - *You can't use 根 for things that have a flat surface*
- **条** can be a measure word for **abstract concepts**. For example, 一条规矩, 一条题目
- **根** is more common when used as a measure word for **tiny things**. For example, 一根绣花针, 一根火柴, 一根松针, 一根头发, 一根汗毛, (all long, thin and tiny)
- **条** can also replace 根 when used as a measure word for tiny things especially objects from living things. For example, 一根头发,  一根汗毛; 一条头发,  一条汗毛

For things that are not huge, tiny, alive or have a flat surface 條 and 根 are often interchangeable. For example, 一条长棍, 一根长棍, 一条短棒, 一根短棒

Comment: 一条题目sounds a little bit weird. I only use道 for 题目. And I don't even know the word 规举， did you mean 规矩？ Also the word巾 doesn't sounds like Mandarin to me, I've only seen multi-syllable words using this character.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 Must be a Cantonese thing to say 一条题目 and 一条规矩

Comment: Never heard of 一条头发, 一条汗毛. 一条烟囱 is odd too. Maybe, the choices for measure words are regional.

Comment: I have never heard of 一根铅笔 neither

Comment: How about 一根木头?

Comment: I think 根 (root) is used for things are straight and sometimes one end is the root or handle while the other end is the head or point.

Comment: You forgot 一条鱼。

Comment: I mentioned 一条蚯蚓, 一条蛇,

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the essential meanings of these two measure words, 条 is the small branch of tree, and 根 is the root of tree. In daily conversation, 条 is used for things that may be long and **wiggly**, such as 一条河(river), while 根 is for long, **straight** objects, such as 一根香菸(cigarette).

Sometimes, 条 and 根 are interchangeable, we can say 一条 or 一根 香蕉(banana), or 香腸(sausage).

Comment: There is an interesting comparison, 一条烟 and 一根烟 are different.

Comment: 一条烟 is one carton of cigarettes, and 一根烟 is just one cigarette.

Answer (score 1):

My experince is that 根 is used for **small and hard** objects such as 铅笔，香蕉，香烟， etc. Well, 条 is usually for **big and soft** ones like 蛇，河，船， 围巾，etc.

Comment: 一枝铅笔 is more common;  and how is 一条船 soft and  一条蚯蚓 big?

Comment: @TangHo 一根铅笔 is common too. 一支铅笔 sounds a little bit formal maybe. 船 is big and 蚯蚓 is soft. I don't think there is a good hard-and-fast rule for it anyway.

Comment: @TangHo 当我第一眼看到铅笔的时候我第一反应也是，不应该是“一支铅笔”吗？但仔细想想，我们那儿（北方）方言，全是说“根”的。“给我来根儿笔”，“给我来根儿烟”，哈哈

Comment: @dan 论“支”是formal还是normal我也说不清了，反正现在北漂在北京，我家孩子是说“支”的，我跟她也说“支”。都快忘了我原来是说“根”的。